# Perl program to find matching words in a paragraph

Tags: perl, compare, pattern-matching

I have two text files.

The first one has a list of words, like the following:

#### File 1.txt

```
Laura
Samuel
Gerry
Peter
Maggie
```

The second one has paragraphs on it. For example

#### File2.txt

```
Laura
is
about
to
meet
Gerry
and
is
planning
to
take
Peter
along
```

All I want the program to do is look for common words and print `MATCH` beside the matching words in `File2.txt` or to a third output file.

So the desired output should look like this.

```
Laura | MATCH
is
about
to
meet
Gerry | MATCH
and
is
planning
to
take
Peter | MATCH
along
```

I have tried the following code, however I am not getting the desired output.

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Data::Dumper;

my $result = { };

my $first_file  = shift || 'File1.txt';
my $second_file = shift || 'File2.txt';
my $output      = 'output2.txt';

open my $a_fh, '<', $first_file  or die "$first_file: $!";
open my $b_fh, '<', $second_file or die "$second_file: $!";

open( OUTPUT,  '>' . $output ) or die "Cannot create $output.\n";

while ( <$a_fh> ) {
    chomp;
    next if /^$/;
    $result->{$_}++;
}

while ( <$b_fh> ) {

    chomp;

    next if /^$/;

    if ( $result->{$_} ) {
        delete $result->{$_};
        $result->{ join " |" => $_, "MATCH" }++;
    }
    else {
        $result->{$_}++;
    }
}

{
    $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 0;
    print OUTPUT Dumper $result;
}
```

But the output that I am getting is like this.

```
Laura  | MATCH
Samuel | MATCH
take
Maggie | MATCH
Laura
about
to
Gerry
meet
Gerry | MATCH
and
is
Maggie |MATCH
planning
to
Peter |MATCH
take
Peter |MATCH
```

The output is not in a paragraph format, nor is it printing `MATCH` for all matches.

Please advise.

Comment: is your "paragraph" file really one word per line?

Comment: For the future, please be more thoroughly when posting. The question itself is not bad and I appreciate that you `use strict` and `use warnings` but you only pretend to: your script doesn't compile as it is. Also the output shown does not reflect your actual output because Data::Dumper uses far more curlies `{}` and arrows `=>` than we can see here.

Comment: My bad for the incompleteness. I actually used a for loop to cleanse the data dumper output ,like this :                                                                           print  $_, $/ for (sort{$a_fh cmp $b_fh} keys %{$result});

Comment: The Perl code that you show won't compile for a number of reasons. It certainly doesn't produce the output that you say it does. There is no point at all in asking a question unless you show your real code and data

Comment: @Borodin thankyou for your reply,but to surprise my initial code actually compiled and executed fine ,just that it was giving an output in the format var { 'Laura | MATCH' =>1 \n 'Samuel |MATCH' =>2 ..... } and i cleansed it using the code $_, $/ for (sort{$a_fh cmp $b_fh} keys %{$result}); . But I am all good now. thanks again

Comment: @Dev: I apologise if it was my mistake. Your current question *does* compile, and the output is this `Use of uninitialized value $_ in scalar chomp at E:\Perl\source\paras.pl line 25, <$b_fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at E:\Perl\source\paras.pl line 27, <$b_fh> line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in scalar chomp at E:\Perl\source\paras.pl line 25, <$b_fh> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in pattern match (m//) at E:\Perl\source\paras.pl line 27, <$b_fh> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value $_ in scalar chomp at E:\Perl\source\paras.pl ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one example, which allows doing multiple files. I populate an array `@files` with the files I want to compare, then I read in the wordlist file and put them all into a hash, then  iterate over the paragraph files one line at a time. I then separate all the words on each line, and print them, but only after checking whether the word is in wordlist. If it is, I print it with " | MATCH".

Paragraph file 1:

```
Laura is about to meet Gerry, and is planning to take Peter along.

But Peter and Sarah have other plans.
```

Paragraph file 2:

```
Blah Peter has lost it.
```

The code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @files = ('file.txt', 'file2.txt');

open my $word_fh, '<', 'wordlist.txt' or die $!;

my %words_to_match = map {chomp $_; $_ => 0} <$word_fh>;

close $word_fh;

check($_) for @files;

sub check {
    my $file = shift;

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

    while (<$fh>){
        chomp;
        my @words_in_line = split;

        for my $word (@words_in_line){
            $word =~ s/[\.,;:!]//g;
            $word .= ' | MATCH' if exists $words_to_match{$word};
            print "    $word\n";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Laura | MATCH
is
about
to
meet
Gerry | MATCH
and
is
planning
to
take
Peter | MATCH
along
But
Peter | MATCH
and
Sarah
have
other
plans

Blah
Peter | MATCH
has
lost
it
```

If you want to print it to a file, open a write file handle, and change the `print` statement inside the while loop to `print $wfh ...`.

Comment: @Dev: Please remember that all Stack Overflow pages are important because of the traffic they will will get *after* you have your answer. Your question shows code that doesn't even compile, and certainly doesn't produce the output that you say it does. That is very selfish of you, and is no help to anyone else who might come across your question in the hope of a solution. Please be more considerate in the future

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't get the desired output because you stuffed it into the hash `$result` and then printed that with `Data::Dumper`.
`Data::Dumper` will print a hash in an arbitrary order, especially if you set `$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys=0`.

I changed your code a bit so the output is written as soon as it's read from File2.txt and when it's clear whether there was a match or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $result      = {};
my $first_file  = shift || 'File1.txt';
my $second_file = shift || 'File2.txt';
my $output      = 'output2.txt';
open my $a_fh, '<', $first_file  or die "$first_file: $!";
open my $b_fh, '<', $second_file or die "$second_file: $!";
open( my $out, '>', $output ) or die "Cannot create $output.\n";

# remember words from File1.txt in the hash $result:
while ( my $line = <$a_fh> ) {
    $line =~ s/^\s*//;    # strip leading whitespace
    $line =~ s/\s*$//;    # strip trailing ws
    next if $line =~ /^$/;    # skip now empty lines
    $result->{$line} = 1;
}

# now $result consists of all "words" in File1.txt, like
# $result = {
#   'Gerry'  => 1,
#   'Laura'  => 1,
#   'Maggie' => 1,
#   'Peter'  => 1,
#   'Samuel' => 1
# };

# now iterate over File2.txt, print all lines and append
# 'MATCH' for those in File1.txt:
while ( my $line = <$b_fh> ) {
    $line =~ s/^\s*//;        # strip leading whitespace
    $line =~ s/\s*$//;        # strip trailing ws
    next if $line =~ /^$/;    # skip now empty lines

    # print the line from File2.txt (without \n):
    print $out $line;

    # if this line (word) was found
    # in File1.txt, then append " | MATCH"
    if ( $result->{$line} ) {
        print $out ' | MATCH';
    }

    # print final \n
    print $out "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Laura | MATCH
is
about
to
meet
Gerry | MATCH
and
is
planning
to
take
Peter | MATCH
along
```