# Search for words ending with 'ing' from a text file in perl

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

I have a text file , lets call it file1.txt :

```
cats
and
dogs
are
running
around
|

john
loves
mary
|

I
am
swimming 
|
```

I am trying to build a program which looks for the words ending with 'ing' and prints CC beside them on the same file or to a different output.txt file.

Desired Output

```
cats
and
dogs
are
running  CC
around
|

john
loves
mary
|

I
am
swimming CC
|
```

I went through the available articles in the forum and tried building the following code ,however it gives me an arbitrary result with every word followed by " CC ".

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'file1.txt';

open(my $word_fh,"file1.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file1.txt, $!";

my %word_match = map {chomp $_; $_ => 0} <$word_fh>;

close $word_fh;


open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

while (<$fh>){
    chomp;

    my @words_in_line = split;

    for my $word (@words_in_line){

        $word =~ /ing$/;
        $word .= '  CC' if exists $word_match{$word};

         print "    $word\n";
    }
    }
```

The output that I get is this :

```
cats    CC
and CC
dogs    CC
are CC
running CC
around  CC
|   CC
john    CC
loves   CC
mary    CC
|   CC
I   CC
am  CC
swimming
|   CC
```

I know I am doing something wrong. Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Straight forward: [**`\w+ing\b`**](https://regex101.com/r/nN4wH9/1) - replace those with `$0 CC` and you're done. `\w+` makes sure letters are preceding, `\b` is a word boundary.

Comment: Uncomment `use strict` and `use warnings`. You'll see that you miss-typed `word_match` line 23 (you added an 's'), and you used twice `$w_fh` instead of `$word_fh`.. (that's not the solution to your question though, but you still should do that)

Comment: The code you show doesn't produce the output that you say it does. If you want us to help you then please show your real code, and especially ***never comment out `use strict` and `use warnings`***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are reading your file1.txt twice and check whether they match. In the `while` loop you print 'CC' if the current line of file1.txt is also contained somewhere in file1.txt. Since they are the same files this is always true and 'CC' is printed after every line.

You might have been inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37899315/5830574) where the OP wanted to check whether words in file A are also contained in file B. Yours is a different case because you don't have two files.

Drop the first reading of file1.txt into `%word_match` and iterate over the file just once. Your line `$word =~ /ing$/;` only checks whether `$word` ends in `ing` but throws the result away. That is like writing

```
$i > 5;
print "i is greater than 5\n";
```

You have to change that to

```
if ( $i > 5 ) {
    print "i is greater than 5\n";
}
```

In summary this gives

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'file1.txt' or die $!;
while ( <$fh> ){
    chomp;
    print $_;
    if ( /ing\s*$/ ) {
        print ' CC';
    }
    print "\n";
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: The program executes ,however prints 'CC' beside the word "running" only. 'cats
and
dogs
are
running CC
around

john
loves
mary

I
am
swimming 
' It doesn't print CC beside swimming..

Comment: `swimming` contains a trailing blank. It actually is `'swimming '`. I updated my answer but you could have figured out that yourself.

Comment: Im not sure if I should post a new question or ask it here itself. Is it possible to include more than one condition in the 'if'section or I should be using 'elsif'. For eg, In addition to getting words ending with 'ing' if I also want to look for words ending with 's' in the same text file and print 'CC' beside them, should I be using an 'elsif' command or I can pass multiple parameters under 'if'? Also, if I want to look for words ending with 'd' and print 'DD' beside them in the same program, should 'elsif' be the best way? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Nandini143: You can write `if ( /ing\s*$/ or /s\s*$/ ) { ... }`. Or you can combine that into a single regex with `if ( /(?:ing|s)\s*$/ ) { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what your code is doing. What, for example, is the point of the `%word_match` hash? And why have you commented out `use strict` and `use warnings`?

It seems likely that you are over-thinking the problem as this seems pretty simple to me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  $_ .= ' CCC' if /ing$/;
  print "$\n";
}
```

This is written as a Unix-style filter. It reads from STDIN and writes to STDOUT. So, (assuming it was in a file called `cccing`) you would call it like this:

```
$ ./cccing < your_input.txt > your_output.txt
```

Comment: We don't know that the platform isn't Windows. `perl cccing.pl ... ` is always safer

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, you are using your hash `%word_match` to test whether each word in the file exists in the same file. Of course that is true for every word, so you get a `CC` appended to everything

Removing the first `open`, the loop that builds the hash, and the test on the hash, I think this is the best way. It will handle multiple words per line as your own code does, and also avoids the need to allow for whitespace in the regex pattern

#### Perl code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 'file1.txt';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ){
    chomp;

    my @words_in_line = split;

    for my $word ( @words_in_line ) {

        $word .= ' CC' if $word =~ /(?:ing|s)$/;
    }

    print "    @words_in_line\n";
}
```

#### input

```
cats
and
dogs
are running around
|

john loves mary
|

I
am
swimming 
|
```

#### output

```
cats CC
and
dogs CC
are running CC around
|

john loves CC mary
|

I
am
swimming CC
|
```